# Moving Salesforce data into Heroku Java app for LDV processing?

Tags: integration, java, largedatavolumes, heroku

I have read a few blog posts about moving parts of an app into a Ruby Heroku app, but no example for moving data between a Salesforce org and a custom Java app on Heroku.

- Do you know of any in posts or articles related to this topic?
- Do you any AppExchange app that is partly using Heroku for processing or storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce are developing a service that will allow you to easily synchronise data in your Saleforce Org and apps running on Heroku (regardless of language).

The synchronisation is done via an Heroku Postgress database and will help manage data transfer at a sustainable rate.

This service will be generally available in 2014 and you can sign up your interest now at: https://www.heroku.com/1

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This webinar might be pertinent:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Webinar:_Extreme_Salesforce_Data_Volumes_(2013-Feb)

Answer (score 1):

Your probably going to have to use some of the [Salesforce data-export tools](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_exportdata.htm) to download your data as a CSV file system.

From there your going to have to create the Schema in your database system on Heroku, and than write an app to import it, or merge the database with a SQL tool.

I am not aware of any apps on the AppExchange that use Heroku as it's backend for storage. There are some that use AWS S3 to store documents / images / etc. to save media there to save on Salesforce storage.

Comment: I think Heroku is a much better choice than AWS as both is owned and hosted by the same company. Besides that I was looking for a totally automatic  (transparent) way of a bidirectional data transport. E.g. an Apex class that connects to a heroku app and creates data in a normal relational db there...

Comment: Yes, such a database link would be an interesting project. I don't know that anyone has made one available publicly, maybe I'm mistaken. To make this work, one would have to theoretically transpose the database and write web service endpoints on both sides.

Comment: Challenge accepted. I've been meaning to dive into Heroku anyways. Wish me luck.